# IntelliJ IDEA: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when setting up SFTP servers

Tags: sftp

I can't seem to set up an SFTP connection for deployment in IntelliJ IDEA. I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` every time I try to get a connection to the server. When setting up an FTP server, I don't get this exception and everything seems to be working fine.

The server is reachable and I double-checked my login details...

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please contact support with [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the idea.log file. I think I found out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to CrazyCoder for pointing out the [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) file. I had only been looking around in the "Event Log", which is pretty empty :-)

When I tailed the log file I found the following Exception:

```
2013-05-25 16:36:37,608 [49048641]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://server01.local/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://server01.local/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:698)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:624)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:121)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:122)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:83)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:266)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.getChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:132)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.SimpleTreeStructure.getChildElements(SimpleTreeStructure.java:25)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$31.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:1618)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1824)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.getChildrenFor(AbstractTreeUi.java:1615)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$4600(AbstractTreeUi.java:60)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$46.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:2702)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1824)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2400(AbstractTreeUi.java:60)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$57$1.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3379)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.WebServerTreeBuilder.runBackgroundLoading(WebServerTreeBuilder.java:90)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$57.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3370)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1824)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2400(AbstractTreeUi.java:60)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3435)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Error during processing known-hosts file "/Users/Robert/.ssh/known_hosts".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(KnownHosts.java:171)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(KnownHosts.java:60)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.setKnownHosts(JSch.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:122)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

It seems like there was something wrong with my `known_hosts` file (`Error during processing known-hosts file "/Users/Robert/.ssh/known_hosts"`). I backed it up and removed it, now everything seems to be working fine. I'll just have to look over which line is being funky, as the `ssh` and `sftp` utilities work just fine from within the Terminal and don't complain about my `known_hosts` file.

Hopefully this comes handy to someone else having the same error.